# Using respectively when two subjects receive the same treatment

Tags: sentence

When describing the fact that A, B and C received treatments 1, 2 and 3, we can write:

```
Subjects A, B and C were tested; and treatments 1, 2 and 3 respectively, were applied.
```

If subjects A, B and C are applied treatments 1, 1 and 2, should we apply the same sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The very simple answer is 'yes'.